# Reverting environment to clean slate for Python in El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, development-environment, uninstallation

I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan. Over the years I have upgraded this Mac numerous times and have jacked up the Python configuration all sorts of ways. Yes, I know a clean install is the best option, but I want to attempt a manual cleanup.

Let's say I want to clean up (uninstall and remove) anything dealing with Python that is not installed by default by OS X. This includes alternate distributions such as Anaconda and package managers like Homebrew and MacPorts which can modify a Python installation's default paths and whatnot if it is installed using them. I can certainly track down instructions for doing all of these steps individually (and have), but it would be good to have a central reference for doing do—particularly when certain combinations of the below or orders of removing them can impact the others. I also don't want to mess up my system's installation of Python.

This reference should include instructions for uninstalling and removing the following:

- Python 2.7 install (by user, not system default install)
- Python 3.x install (by user, not system default install)
- Anaconda Python distribution installation
- Any MacPorts installations of Python
- Any Homebrew installations of Python
- Any Python packages that don't ship with the OS

All of the following should be addressed:

- Repairing system paths
- Ensuring pip works as intended for the system default installations
- Removing any extraneous lingering files from removed installations

Comment: I almost didn't ask this in fear of it being closed as too broad, but I've learned that the order in which these removals are carried out matters and messing with one thing can mess up another.